# Run angular repository locally

Tags: node.js, angular, github, npm, localhost

There is Angular repository on GitHub github.com/angular/angular. Could it be run locally via localhost ? README for repository do not provide any instruction for running locally. Running 'yarn' builds site, and how to lunch it with local server ? 'Contributing to code' gives no option to run site locally.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help anyone ... Answering my own question the steps to run github.com/angular/angular locally would be:

1. main site is located in folder 'aio'
2. inside this folder is readme file with detailed instructions but there are several point not mentioned in file that are worth to notice for novice users like me
   2.1. if repository was downloaded from github as zip file then the one need to run 'git init' in the root folder 'angular'
   2.2. before executing any yarn / npm command i ran 'nvm use' which proposed to install '16.10.0' node version
   2.3. I am on windows 10 and thus used WSL as command line tool and had to install python, g++, make and possibly other software indicated by cmd on fails
3. Next, simply execute 'yarn setup' to build all the staff and start site with 'yarn start' which runs on localhost:4200
   While clearing how to run site I issued 'npm run presetup' but it seems that this command had no effect on final result. Not sure, but I got that content of folder ./content/examples/ was erased, possibly while running 'npm run presetup', and immediately after start of 'yarn setup' I checked if folder examples is not empty, I found it empty and simply copied content form original zip to this folder while 'yarn setup' was executed. Otherwise there would be issued .gitignore error while running 'yarn setup' and overall build would fails.

I also tried to run old Angular site from github angular.io that is archived since 2019. The parent folder where I placed angular.io should contain github folder 'angular' with version 4.3.3.  I succeeded to run angular.io under condition that looks unusual to me because I had to build site with node 6.9.0 and run it with node 10. It looks as inconsistency apply different node version for build and running site. The one should build site using node version 6, i used 6.9.0. However in order to lunch site on localhost I had to switch 'nvm use' to node 10 (after initial build) and run again ./scripts/before-install.sh as this script installs gulp that could be accessed by node 10. Without switching to node 10 there are produced a lot of weird errors. README provides several commands  to run site, i succeeded only with 'gulp serve-and-sync-devguide'.